# Does an Azure subscription owner have access to an Azure database in it?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles) says that an Azure subscription owner has access to all the resources in the subscription. However to get access to an Azure database, one must either be a user in the database, or be part of the Azure Admin AD group.

Can a subscription owner access the database regardless of the SQL security? If so, how?

Comment: it's a good question ,in my understanding, if he is the global administrator ,he can  do ANYTHING ,othere than that i debends 
 check here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles

Comment: If we look at specific resources such as Storage, KeyVault and Cosmos DB, Owners and Contributors do not have access to the data, unless users are given a specific role. 

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal

Comment: Is there any specific resource you are referring to?

Comment: @LMGagne I am pretty sure that a subscription owner has access to Storage data regardless of other assigned roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you refer to gives a very high-level overview on RBAC roles provided in Azure.

It is important to understand these built-in roles that give access to the resources (the management plane) vs those that give access to the resource data (the data plane).

For example, many built-in roles give users access to data, for example: Storage and KeyVault.

As for databases, it all depends on the type of database engine your refer to. Each have specific particularities in terms of roles and permissions.

SQL Database is managed right in the SQL server. This link provides additional details on how this is done. [SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins)

Other modern database engines, such as Cosmos DB, come with different Azure Built-in roles (just like Key Vault or Storage). See this link in order to give you a better idea on the roles and permissions assigned for each roles. [Role-based access control in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/role-based-access-control)